# How to use matplotlib to plot the following graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I have a graph that looks like this. It's a histogram and the x-axis is in a decreasing order.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **invert_axis()**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(1000)  

plt.hist(data, bins=20, density=True)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Descending Histogram')
plt.show()
```

[image: output]